# I want to set time to visible message with AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a use case where I am reading the time from DB in every 30mins and if found time to be executed in next 30mins I put in a AWS SQS.

**Example-** I am running cron every 30 mins with lambda that reads `schedule_at` from DB. And find tasks which needs to be execute in next 30mins I put it in a AWS SQS queue;
Like the cron run time is 11:30 and the tasks is scheduled at 11:16. I want to add them to queue and only execute it when 11:16 time(which is `schedule_at` it would be different for every tasks).

Here I want to set the time to execute the message, or visible only when time `schedule_at` time and at that time it will trigger another lambda to deal with business logic.

I am not sure how to solve this using what attribs of AWS SQS, Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can delay message visibility for up to 15 minutes.

Since you don't specify what SDK you're using, here's the [API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html); look at `DelaySeconds`. And note that it only works for a "standard" SQS queue, not a FIFO queue.